# Updating DateTime to database is throwing SqlTypeException - SqlDateTime overflow

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-contrib

Executing following line of code:

```
conn.Update(CashInItem)
```

throws an exception:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM  (line 465 in Contrib `var updated = connection.Execute(sb.ToString(), entityToUpdate, commandTimeout: commandTimeout, transaction: transaction);`)

I am testing Dapper.Contrib.
I have a table in SQL Server that has a few `DateTime` columns - some of them allow NULL values.
I created an object with properties to match the columns in the table. For the `DateTime` columns, the properties are nullable.

Here is an example of one of the properties:

```
public DateTime? ReconciledOn { get; set; }
```

I first use `IDbConnection.Query` method to get a record from the SQL table. This runs OK and the object mapping is fine. When I check on of the nullable `DateTime` values it shows `null`.

I then, make a simple change to string parameter and call the following:

```
static bool Update(CashIn CashInItem)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        return conn.Update(CashInItem); //Error on this line
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning up my code it worked.

At first, I was testing just Dapper and then added Dapper.Contrib. I had references to both.  I now believe that the reason was that the object was loaded using Dapper.Query which was then used in Dapper.Contrib Update. After cleaning my code looks like that

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string dump = "";
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AchieveDB"].ConnectionString)){
  conn.Open();
  CashIn oCashIn = conn.Get<CashIn>(59458);
  dump = ObjectDumper.Dump(oCashIn);
  Console.WriteLine(dump);
  Console.WriteLine("Updating");
  Console.WriteLine("=========");

  oCashIn.ReconciledOn = DateTime.Now;
  dump = ObjectDumper.Dump(oCashIn);
  Console.WriteLine(dump);
  conn.Update <CashIn>(oCashIn);
}
```

References:
    `using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Dapper.Contrib;
    using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
    using ObjectDumping;`

The SQL statements Contrib sent to the database:
For the Get 
`exec sp_executesql N'select * from CashIn where CashInId = @id',N'@id int',@id=59458`

For the Update
`exec sp_executesql N'update CashIn set [ -- then all Fields = matching param then list of params and values.`

Answer (score 1):

You are using SQL datatype [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to store value in SQL Server. The valid range of values for this datatype is:

> January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

To represent this column in your code, you are using C# datatype [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8#quick-links-to-remarks-topics). The valid range of values for this datatype is:

> The DateTime value type represents dates and times with values ranging from 00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era) through 11:59:59 P.M., December 31, 9999 A.D. (C.E.) in the Gregorian calendar.

Your C# property is nullable; but that is not a problem.

Problem is, somewhere in your code, you are instantiating the property to `new DateTime()` which then holds its default value `01-Jan-0001 12:00:00 AM` which ultimately is out of the valid range of SQL datatype and hence the exception.

You have not provided enough code in question; so you have to debug this yourself where this assignment is happening.

Comment: First - thanks for reviewing my question. I suspected something like that. As I mentioned I am checking the value of the two nullable datetime fields just before calling the update method and both return null (?oCashInItem.ReconciledOn -> null). So I was wondering if somewhere in the code of Update method it might doing it. I will answer my own question with relevant code.